# Can redis set a new list by an array in one command

Tags: redis

Because I want to use `lrange` command of Redis, I try to use the document type `list` of Redis.

e.g.

```
rpush myl "1"
rpush myl "2"
lrange myl 0 -1
```

and we get

```
1) "1"
2) "2"
```

My problem is that sometimes I want to set a whole new list rather than set single element 1-by-1(like command `lset`).

Is it possible to set my list use command like

```
setl myl ["1", "2", "3"]
lrange myl 0 -1
```

and get

```
1) "1"
2) "2"
3) "3"
```

(Override previous list)

Comment: `DEL` the list, then reinsert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, didn't read through. Maybe wrap `DEL`and `RPUSH` into a transaction?

```
MULTI
DEL mylist
RPUSH mylist a b c
EXEC
```

Although I don't know if there is a single command to do this whole thing.

Comment: Hi Thanks for response, but the command I need is set a whole new list  rather than push multiple elements. I further clarify myself in the problem description. Thanks